# Rotate string counterclockwise

Tags: java, strings

Here is the function I have come up with. Any improvements possible?

E.g LeetCode -> rotate by 2 -> deLeetCo

```
public static String rotateAntiClockWise(String s, int offset){
    int i = offset%s.length();
    StringBuffer prefix = new StringBuffer();
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        prefix.append(s.charAt(s.length()-1-j));
    }
    return prefix.append(s.substring(0, s.length()-i)).toString();
}
```

Comment: Why isn't the expected result `deLeetCo`?  That is what you get if you rotate the characters.  Is the source of this challenge [this question from LintCode](http://www.lintcode.com/en/problem/rotate-string)?  If so, then you've misread the problem.

Comment: @JS1 - Thanks for pointing out the error in question. I have edited it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
>     for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
>         prefix.append(s.charAt(s.length()-1-j));
>     }
> ```

An easy optimization is to change this to

```
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        prefix.append(s.charAt(s.length() - j));
    }
```

You can go further if you like, e.g.

```
    for (int j = s.length() - 1, m = s.length - i; j >= m; j--) {
        prefix.append(s.charAt(j));
    }
```

But if you're doing that, you might as well change

> ```
> public static String rotateAntiClockWise(String s, int offset){
>     int i = offset%s.length();
>     StringBuffer prefix = new StringBuffer();
>     for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
>         prefix.append(s.charAt(s.length()-1-j));
>     }
>     return prefix.append(s.substring(0, s.length()-i)).toString();
> }
> ```

to

```
public static String rotateAntiClockWise(String s, int offset){
    int i = s.length() - (offset % s.length());
    StringBuffer prefix = new StringBuffer();

    for (int j = s.length() - 1; j >= i; j--) {
        prefix.append(s.charAt(j));
    }

    return prefix.append(s.substring(0, i)).toString();
}
```

Now we only subtract from `s.length()` twice.  Before we subtracted from it `i + 1` times.

But I actually think that the best version is

```
public static String rotateAntiClockWise(String s, int offset){
    int i = s.length() - (offset % s.length());
    StringBuffer prefix = new StringBuffer(s.substring(i));

    return prefix.reverse().append(s.substring(0, i)).toString();
}
```

Now I can easily read this and see that we are reversing the last part of the string and appending the first part.

I'm not really feeling the `rotateAntiClockWise` name.  That's not really what we're doing.  We're more `mirrorSuffixToPrefix` or something.